# Binding object instances to static closures

Tags: php, binding, static, closures, instance

Is it possible to bind an instance to a static closure, or to create a non-static closure inside of a static class method?

This is what I mean...

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    public static function testMethod() {
        $testInstance = new TestClass();
        $testClosure = function() use ($testInstance) {
            return $this === $testInstance;
        };

        $bindedTestClosure = $testClosure->bindTo($testInstance);

        call_user_func($bindedTestClosure);
        // should be true
    }
}

TestClass::testMethod();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP always binds the parent `this` and `scope` to newly created closures. The difference between a static closure and a non-static closure is that a static closure has `scope` (!= NULL) but not `this` at **create time**.
A "top-level" closure has neither `this` nor `scope`.

Therefore, one has to get rid of the scope when creating the closure. Fortunately `bindTo` allows exactly that, even for static closures:

```
$m=(new ReflectionMethod('TestClass','testMethod'))->getClosure()->bindTo(null,null);
$m();
```

Comment: So you are saying thet scope (not this ehich is already null) needs be removed to make it a non-static closure?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may not be possible, from [Closure::bindTo documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php)

> Static closures cannot have any bound object (the value of the parameter newthis should be NULL), but this function can nevertheless be used to change their class scope.

Comment: That's my point. How do you make a non-static closure inside a static method?